# How to set up an Azure VMSS autoscale rule based on the sum of queue message counts of multiple service buses?

Tags: azure, autoscaling

My VMs subscribe to queues on multiple service buses, sometimes across multiple Azure regions. How do I create an Azure VMSS autoscale rule that is based on the sum of queue message counts of multiple service buses?

Comment: I guess (VMSS) autoscale rules currently support metrics from a single resource.
If you want this maybe a custom solution should be prepared.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is what you mean, but there's Service Bus metrics through Azure Monitor in this Microsoft documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/autoscale/autoscale-common-metrics#commonly-used-service-bus-metrics

Otherwise I would probably look into Azure Automation. There's KEDA for k8s, but that's not going to help you here. I'd suggest you'll probably need to write something since that documentation is for a single queue.